# SwiftUI: Drawing a line between two views in a list / how to determine the center location of a view?

Tags: foreach, swiftui, view, location, center

I want to draw a line between a selected source-View and a selected target-View when I press the "connect" button.
As far as I understand I need the (center?) CGPoint of these views...
How can I determine the center CGPoint of a view inside a forEach-HStack-list?

Elements from both lists will be removed/added.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTarget: Int = 0
    @State private var selectedSource: Int = 3
    @State private var isConnected = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
       
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<6) { index in
                        Text("Target \(index)")
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(selectedTarget == index ? .red : .black)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selectedTarget = index
                            }
                    }
                }
                
                List {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
                .border(.black, width: 2)
        
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<6) { index in
                        Text("Source \(index)")
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(selectedSource == index ? .orange : .black)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selectedSource = index
                            }
                    }
                }
                Button(isConnected ? "CUT" : "CONNECT") {
                    isConnected.toggle()
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the rough demo code and take an idea from this code.
You can achieve this by first finding the position of the `Text` by `GeometryReader` and draw the path between those points.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTarget: Int = 0
    @State private var selectedSource: Int = 3
    @State private var isConnected = false
    
    @State private var targetCGPoint: CGPoint = .zero
    @State private var sourceCGPoint: CGPoint = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            if isConnected {
                getPath()
            }
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<6) { index in
                        GeometryReader { geo in
                        Text("Target \(index)")
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(selectedTarget == index ? Color.red : Color.black)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                let size = geo.size
                                targetCGPoint = CGPoint(x: geo.frame(in: .global).origin.x + (size.width / 2), y: geo.frame(in: .global).origin.y)
                                print("Target Global center: \(geo.frame(in: .global).midX) x \(geo.frame(in: .global).midY)")
                                selectedTarget = index
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                // Removed list for demo
                Spacer()
                
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<6) { index in
                        GeometryReader { geo in
                            Text("Source \(index)")
                                .padding()
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .background(selectedSource == index ? Color.orange : Color.black)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    let size = geo.size
                                    sourceCGPoint = CGPoint(x: geo.frame(in: .global).origin.x + (size.width / 2), y: geo.frame(in: .global).origin.y)
                                    print("Source Global center: \(geo.frame(in: .global).midX) x \(geo.frame(in: .global).midY)")
                                    selectedSource = index
                                }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                Button(isConnected ? "CUT" : "CONNECT") {
                    isConnected.toggle()
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func getPath() -> some View {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: sourceCGPoint)
            path.addLine(to: targetCGPoint)
        }
        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 10)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: this is what I was looking for. thanks for your help!